Is there any easy way to Integrate angular component into react
Is there any easy way to Integrate angular component into react without using react-ang?
Focusing on performance.
Used react-ang, which allows you to use Angular components in React.
Used the Wrapper Component in React App
The wrapper component in React application is like any other React component.

Have you tried using @angular/elements? I once needed to use an Angular component in React, and this package made it much easier for us.
